# Is there a measure of AI relative strength, modified by resources?

Tags: classification, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, game-theory

For instance, Strength/Size$\times$Speed, where size and speed refer to memory and processing.

We now have very strong, narrow AI, but they tend to run on fast hardware without volume restrictions.

To understand why I'm asking, this article on BBC may provide some insight: "[Which life form dominates Earth?](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20150211-whats-the-most-dominant-life-form)"  (If I was a betting man, I'd put money on [tardigrades](http://www.amnh.org/var/ezflow_site/storage/images/media/amnh/images/exhibitions/current-exhibitions/life-at-the-limits/tardigrade/1849316-2-eng-US/tardigrade_imagelarge.jpg) outlasting humans, and the secret of their success is that they require minimal resources and processing power, unlike higher-order automata.)

Comment: Can you just give us a glimpse of what that AI is? is it a game,a living creature?

Comment: @quintumnia They're currently in the very early stage of development, but the scope of the first stage automata is described here: [Epimetheus](http://www.fundamentalcombinatronics.com/epimetheus/). The game complexity will ultimately range from < Chess to > Go, where the immediate, practical need is for local, constrained, weak, general AI. (The model is a fundamental economic "metagame", based on a small set of combinatorial mechanics with an alarming range of extensions, i.e. the product.)  Right now I'm just trying to get a gauge on similar initiatives, since I'm still new to the field.